# Protect rails backend servers from direct connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, frontend, backend, thin

It is classical scheme of serving Rails application: frontend is Apache (nginx, etc) on 80 port, and backend : cluster of mongrel (thin, unicorn, etc) on some other ports (for example 3000,3001,3002...).

How make, that back-end servers allow **only** local (from frontend) connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the connection by socket, you are sur to be only in local.

After you can say to some server to accept only 127.0.0.0 request. Byt example with thin

```
thin start -a 127.0.0.0
```

The -a options is :

```
-a, --address HOST               bind to HOST address (default: 0.0.0.0)
```

A good practice too is to add some Firewall to avoid all connection  by anywhere to your proxy port.